# How to Read This below JSON Code Data in PHP for every value

Tags: php, mysql, json, api

```
{
    "data": {
        "orderId": "10946506",
        "status": "FAILED",
        "mobile": "9795681183",
        "amount": "100.00",
        "transId": "",
        "error_code": "119",
        "service": "Airtel",
        "bal": "",
        "creditUsed": "0",
        "resText": "Ip 185.27.134.67 Not Configured",
        "gstMode": "P2P",
        "tdsAmount": "0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using PHP native function `json_decode`, here the example :

```
<?php

$json ='{"data":{"orderId":"10946506","status":"FAILED","mobile":"9795681183","amount":"100.00","transId":"","error_code":"119","service":"Airtel","bal":"","creditUsed":"0","resText":"Ip 185.27.134.67 Not Configured","gstMode":"P2P","tdsAmount":"0"}}';
$result = json_decode($json);

//Array
print_r($result);

//single data
echo $result->data->orderId;


?>
```

Comment: Millon Thanks Bro ...Somewhat its working.....rest of the work now will be easy just because of you bro....