# How to get a json value with php with arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am looking to load the "description" of this json with php. I have absolutely no clue how to do this.

```
{"embeds":[{"title":"Test Title","description":"I love php","color":16559363}]}
```

I just want to print "description" and not anything else.

Comment: _" have absolutely no clue how to do this."_ - then you should do some research, and go and find yourself a beginner tutorial that explains such basics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Read This below JSON Code Data in PHP for every value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449951/how-to-read-this-below-json-code-data-in-php-for-every-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your JSON is in a string named `$json`, it would be something like this:

```php
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->embeds[0]->description;
```

Comment: `$json =  '{"embeds":[{"title":"Test Title","description":"I love php","color":16559363}]}';`